# How to return two array of objects from one function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a enum on front end side like this

```
const listCodes = {
    makePay: 'makePay',
    billPay: 'billPay',
    yesPay: 'yesPay'
}
```

Now, I am getting the following response from server

```
const response = [{'entitle': ['makePay', 'yesPay'], 'nonEntitle': ['billPay']}]
const entitled  =  getList(response[0]?.entitle)
const nonentitle = getList(response[0]?.nonEntitle)
```

Now, I am trying to get these data

```
const getList = (list) => Object.keys(listCodes).filter((makePayList) => list?.includes(makePayList))
```

Here I am calling this two times. Is there any way through which we can return both from one method it self ?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what is expected

Comment: What is the usefulness of `getList`? Do you expect other values that need to be filtered away? You write you use it "to get these data", but you already have them before calling `getList`....

Comment: Use `map` function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, a function can return an object/array, which encapsulates the multiple return values you want to get. The receiver can use a destructuring assignment to immediately extract those different parts into different variables.

For instance:

```js
const listCodes = {
    makePay: 'makePay',
    billPay: 'billPay',
    yesPay: 'yesPay'
};

const filterLists = obj =>
    ["entitle", "nonEntitle"].map(key =>
        obj[key].filter(code => code in listCodes)
    );

const response = [{'entitle': ['makePay', 'yesPay'], 'nonEntitle': ['billPay']}]
const [entitled, nonEntitle] = filterLists(response[0]);

console.log(entitled);
console.log(nonEntitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way of doing it:

```js
const listCodes = {
  makePay: 'makePay',
  billPay: 'billPay',
  yesPay: 'yesPay'
};

const response = [{'entitle': ['makePay', 'yesPay'], 'nonEntitle': ['billPay']}]

const {entitle, nonEntitle} = response && response[0] ? response[0] : {}

console.log(entitle);
console.log(nonEntitle);
```

It is a little unclear what you are asking in the last part of your question. But from what it looks like I have mentioned the simplified code for what you seem to be trying to achieve. You don't even need an additional function.